# Convert Clause to list

Tags: prolog

Could someone explain me how can I convert

```
:- op(500, xfy, v).
conver(X,List)
```

I would use it as converter to list like:

```
convert(p v q v r, L)
```

Which as result return list where are only variables:

```
L= [p,q,r]
```

Comment: Why is `v` not in you list `[p,q,r]` ?

Comment: @GuyCoder I will remove it from this list. But could be with v  but still i dont know how write it.

Comment: Do you want just the variables from the expression? At present I am guessing as to what you want, and if I have to guess I typically don't answer.

Comment: @GuyCoder Yes, i do. I want get in my list only variables.

Comment: Then say that you only need the variables for the expression in the question. We don't read minds.

Comment: @GuyCoder done. Could u help me?

Comment: As you are new and already leaving parts of the question out that are relevant I will not answer because there is a good chance you will add more to the question after I answer it. :) If this were my problem I would create a BNF of the expressions, then create a DCG and use that to transform the input expression into a list of variables.

Comment: @GuyCoder Now it's ok wont change anything in my question. But that what u say its too hard for me, could u explain me that a little bit simpler?

Comment: My guess is that you will have more the `v` as an operator and as such will have to have rules that separate operators from variables. So you would use [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) to describe the patterns. e.g. [Boolean expression BNF](https://unnikked.ga/how-to-build-a-boolean-expression-evaluator-518e9e068a65) . Then you would convert the BNF into a Prolog [tag:dcg]. Then once the DCG is working you would modify it to only output the variables. There are easy ways to do this, but again you are not listing out the exact rules and so your question will change.